# Swift CoreData saving a one-to-one relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, save, one-to-one

Below I have a handful of segmented controls that I'm trying to save using `CoreData`. It seems pretty straight forward, but only the most recent control index is being saved. The rest are being reset to 0 for some reason. I have unchecked the default setting for each attribute.

`Quote` is my main entity and has a one-to-one relationship with `Worksheet` called `worksheet`.

```
@IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   let worksheet = Worksheet(context: context)

   switch sender.tag {
   case 0:
      worksheet.irrigation = Int32(irrigationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
   case 1:
      worksheet.waste = Int32(wasteSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
   case 2:
      worksheet.water = Int32(waterSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
   default:
      break
   }

   if let quote = currentQuote as? Quote {
      quote.worksheet = worksheet
      appD.saveContext()
   }
 }
```

UPDATE: It occurred to me to get rid of the switch statement altogether...and now it saves properly. But I'd still like to know why the values were being reset. Maybe an Int attribute automatically gets set to zero when its context is saved but it has no value? It seems like that's what the default value setting would do. Except mine were all unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the `segmentPressed` function is executed, a new `Worksheet` object is created (with default values for all its attributes).  Your code as written (with the `switch` statement) sets the value for only one attribute, depending on which segmented control has been tapped.  As you note with your update, after removing the switch statement, your code updates the values for all the attributes, and all appears good.

However, since you are creating a new `Worksheet` object each time, you need to consider what's happening to the old ones.  As the relationship is one-one, when you assign your new `Worksheet` to the `currentQuote`, the link to the old `Worksheet` object is removed - but the old `Worksheet` object remains.  You are therefore building up a group of "orphaned" `Worksheet` objects which have no link to any `Quotes`.

To avoid this, you should check whether the `currentQuote` has an existing `Worksheet` object.  If so, update the appropriate attribute of that object; if not, create a new `Worksheet`, set its attribute values (you might want to set all of them) and set the relationship to the `currentQuote`.  Something like this:

```
@IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if let worksheet = currentQuote?.worksheet {
        switch sender.tag {
            case 0:
                worksheet.irrigation = Int32(irrigationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            case 1:
                worksheet.waste = Int32(wasteSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            case 2:
                worksheet.water = Int32(waterSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            default:
                break
        }
        appD.saveContext()
    } else {
        if let quote = currentQuote as? Quote {
            let worksheet = Worksheet(context: context)
            worksheet.irrigation = Int32(irrigationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            worksheet.waste = Int32(wasteSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            worksheet.water = Int32(waterSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
            quote.worksheet = worksheet
            appD.saveContext()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a great explanation, thank you. I have a handful of text boxes and a text view as well, so now I test if the worksheet is nil in ViewDidLoad and call an initialization method if necessary.